# Can't create new pen in a new class I created

Tags: c#, winforms

I just made a new class, but I can't seem to create a new Pen or Graphics or whatever...
I openend a new project, and added a new class. So when I try to type:

```
Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.Black);
```

There's an error saying:

> "The type or namespace name 'Pen' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

So what should I do now?

Comment: Did you add `System.Drawing.dll` assembly as a reference ? If you already added it, be sure you have `using System.Drawing;` top of your code.

Comment: When I check my preferences (through my solution explorer), there is a System.Drawing... I that's what you mean.

Comment: System.Drawing.dll should be in the project references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a using directive at the top of your file:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Also, within the IDE, if you click on the Pen type that has the error, you will see a blue rectangle below it, hover your mouse over that and you will get a menu that gives you options to automatically do that:

[image]

You can also bring up this binding menu using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I guess the reference was already there. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add System.Drawing.dll as a reference, then add a `using` directive at the top of the .cs file:

`using System.Drawing;`

That should fix your problem!

Comment: I can't seem to add System.Drawing.dll
There's an error saying it could not be added. - Add a refference to the .NET assembly instead

Comment: Right click on project references and click on add reference.  Go to the .NET tab and look for System.Drawing.dll

Comment: And the weird thing is: I CAN create a new Pen in my program.cs. But not in the new class I created...

Comment: Put a `using System.Drawing;` at the top of the file.